# How to get total count of paged data using query.v1

Tags: versionone

How do I get the total count of results when paging with the `query.v1` endpoint?

### rest-1.v1/Data

A request like this:

```
/rest-1.v1/Data/Member?page=2,0
```

returns the following:

```
<Assets total="4" pageSize="2" pageStart="0">...
```

Note the attribute `total="4"`.

### query.v1

Whereas a query like this:

```
{
  "from": "Story",
  "page":
  {
    "start":0,
    "size":2
  }
}
```

returns the following:

```
[
    [
        {
            "_oid": "Story:1007"
        },
        {
            "_oid": "Story:1015"
        }
    ]
]
```

Note the lack of any total count.

Is there possibly some special parameter I can provide in the select statement to include the count? (Similar to `@Count` with the `rest-1.v1/Data` endpoint?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, here is a solution to count results using two queries:

```
[
    {
        "from": "Scope",
        "select":["Workitems:Story[AssetState!='Dead'].@Count"],
        "filter":["ID='Scope:0'"]
    },
    {
        "from": "Story",
        "select": ["Name"],
        "filter":["Scope='Scope:0'","AssetState!='Dead'"],
        "page":
            {
                "start":0,
                "size":200
            }
    }
]
```

Some clarification on line 4:

```
"select":["Workitems:Story[AssetState!='Dead'].@Count"]
```

After "Workitems" we are down-casting the collection to "Story", and then filtering where the "AssetState" isn't "Dead" to get active stories and finally counting Workitems.

Here you will find some references and extra documentation:

[VersionOne Grammars](https://github.com/versionone/Grammars)

Comment: Is there any advantage to using the `filter` operator versus the `where` operator?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this information is not by default present when using query.v1 endpoint, as it is with rest-1.v1. But here is a workaround you could use, with a two query approach.

```
[
    {
        "from": "Scope",
        "select":["Workitems.@Count"],
        "filter":["ID='Scope:0'","Workitems.AssetType='Story'"]
    },
    {
        "from": "Story",
        "select": ["Name"],
        "filter":["Scope='Scope:0'"],
        "page":
        {
            "start":0,
            "size":2
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: It seems that AssetTypes of `Story`, `Task`, and `Test` are equivalent, since filtering on those types yields the same results. Is there a way to limit the results to only `Story` items?

Comment: Actually, I think that the second filter you provide is invalid. `Workitems` is a collection which doesn't have a member called `AssetType`. For some reason their API just ignores the invalid filter.

Answer (score 0):

@LaureanoRemedi answered the question but I wanted to expand on it to accommodate filtering `Workitems` by more than just `Scope`.

Say, for example, we wanted to count the number of tasks belonging to a Story. We can use the down-cast-and-filter syntax to filter `Task`s belonging to that `Scope` by their `Parent` attribute:

```
"Workitems:Task[Parent='Story:1007'].@Count"
```

With that, we can build a multi-query request:

```
[{
  "from": "Scope",
  "where": {"ID":"Scope:1000"},
  "select": [ "Workitems:Task[Parent='Story:1007'].@Count" ]
},
{
   "from": "Task",
   "where": { "Parent": "Story:1007" }
}]
```

That returns the count as well as the results:

```
[
    [
        {
            "_oid": "Scope:1000",
            "Workitems:Task[Parent='Story:1007'].@Count": "2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "_oid": "Task:1008"
        },
        {
            "_oid": "Task:1009"
        }
    ]
]
```